# Formatting a line with VBA Userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform, code-formatting

I have created a `userform` and I am have a small conundrum. How do I set the text to go a certain `color` if a value in the `userform` has been selected? What I am wanting to do is, if the SP.Value in the combo box is "Yes" then I want the whole iRow text to be Red, if the ST.Value is Yes I want the whole iRow to be blue. I hope this makes sense? The SP.Value and ST.Value are both combo boxes within the userform with just options of "Yes / No"

I am getting the error With Object must be user-defined type, Object or Variant

```
Private Sub NL_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sp Br")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

If SP.Value = "Yes" Then
    With iRow
    .colour = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
    Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B2").Value = Customer.Value
    Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B3").Value = Project.Value
    Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B4").Value = Format(Now, ["DD/MM/YYYY"])
    Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B5").Value = RSM.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Cf.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = RT.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = MEqu.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = hmm.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = wmm.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Opt.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Tap.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Fing.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = col.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Pr.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Qt.Value
    End With
End If

'Insert a row beneath the data to push down footer image
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

'clear form values
    CustRef.Value = ""
    RadType.Value = ""
    MysonEquiv.Value = ""
    heightmm.Value = ""
    widthmm.Value = ""
    Output.Value = ""
    Tapping.Value = ""
    Fixing.Value = ""
    colour.Value = ""
    Price.Value = ""
    Qty.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Unusually perhaps the error message summarises the problem well. You are following a `With` statement with `iRow` which is a Long. Perhaps you mean `Rows(iRow)`?

Answer (score 1):

As SJR pointed out your iRow holds a long numerical value, 12345578 etc so you can't really do anything 'with' it (well, you could but that's beside the point). You're already there with your ws.cells code; iRow holds the row number and you specify a column. So, remove your with block and use cells and rows references for the first few lines:

```
If SP.Value = "Yes" Then
    Rows(iRow).colour = -16776961
    Rows(iRow).TintAndShade = 0
    Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B2").Value = Customer.Value
    Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B3").Value = Project.Value
    Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B4").Value = Format(Now, ["DD/MM/YYYY"])
    Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B5").Value = RSM.Value
    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Cf.Value

' etc
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry I didn't mean to click down on that... I have upped the answer. Thanks for sending me in the right direction, sadly the solution provided still yielded back an error or 2. After consulting the color pallet and MSDN I found that changing my code to the below has now worked.

```
Private Sub NL_Click()

Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Spec Break")


iRow = ws.Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1


If Specials.Value = "Yes" Then
    With Rows(iRow)
        .Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B2").Value = Customer.Value
            Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B3").Value = Project.Value
            Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B4").Value = Format(Now, ["DD/MM/YYYY"])
            Sheets("Spec Break").Range("B5").Value = RSM.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Cf.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = RT.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = MEqu.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = hmm.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 5).Value = wmm.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 6).Value = Opt.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Tap.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 8).Value = Fix.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 9).Value = col.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 10).Value = Pr.Value
                ws.Cells(iRow, 11).Value = Qt.Value
    End With
End If

End Sub
```